# How to get attached image alt text in media.php?

Tags: images

First of all, i apologize for my English. I want to get **attached image alt text** following code in wp-includes/media.php

```
function img_caption_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ) {
    // New-style shortcode with the caption inside the shortcode with the link and image tags.
    if ( ! isset( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
        if ( preg_match( '#((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?<img [^>]+>(?:\s*</a>)?)(.*)#is', $content, $matches ) ) {
            $content = $matches[1];
            $attr['caption'] = trim( $matches[2] );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Filter the default caption shortcode output.
    *
    * If the filtered output isn't empty, it will be used instead of generating
    * the default caption template.
    *
    * @since 2.6.0
    *
    * @see img_caption_shortcode()
    *
    * @param string $output  The caption output. Default empty.
    * @param array  $attr    Attributes of the caption shortcode.
    * @param string $content The image element, possibly wrapped in a hyperlink.
    */
    $output = apply_filters( 'img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content );
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => '',
        'class'   => '',
        'alt'   => '',
    ), $attr, 'caption' );

    $atts['width'] = (int) $atts['width'];
    if ( $atts['width'] < 1 || empty( $atts['caption'] ) )
        return $content;

    if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) )
        $atts['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $atts['id'] ) . '" ';

    $class = trim( 'wp-caption ' . $atts['align'] . ' ' . $atts['class'] );

    if ( current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'caption' ) ) {
        return '<figure ' . $atts['id'] . 'style="width: ' . (int) $atts['width'] . 'px;" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">'
        . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">' . $atts['caption'] . '</figcaption></figure>';
    }

    $caption_width = 10 + $atts['width'];

    /**
    * Filter the width of an image's caption.
    *
    * By default, the caption is 10 pixels greater than the width of the image,
    * to prevent post content from running up against a floated image.
    *
    * @since 3.7.0
    *
    * @see img_caption_shortcode()
    *
    * @param int    $caption_width Width of the caption in pixels. To remove this inline style,
    *                              return zero.
    * @param array  $atts          Attributes of the caption shortcode.
    * @param string $content       The image element, possibly wrapped in a hyperlink.
    */

    $caption_width = apply_filters( 'img_caption_shortcode_width', $caption_width, $atts, $content );

    $style = '';
    if ( $caption_width )
        $style = 'style="width: ' . (int) $caption_width . 'px" '; 

    return '<h3>' . $atts['caption'] . '</h3><div ' . $atts['id'] . $style . 'class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '">'
    . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $alt_text . '</p></div>';
}
```

What can I write instead **$alt_text** variable for i get attached image alt text?

Comment: Questions in the form of "do it for me" rarely get answered.  Consider posting details of what you have tried, code examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the answers to [this forum post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-alternate-text-from-attachments) is mentioned that

```
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

will get the job done for you. Maybe you should give that a try and look at the further information there.

Comment: Hi flomei. This code doesn't work. I tried it before. Following code is correctly work.

$img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$alt_text = get_post_meta( $img_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true  );

But i don't just want to apply to the post thumbnails. I want to apply to every attached image. Do you understand me?

Comment: I think I do. You can retrieve the ID for any attachment, so you should be able to retrieve the meta data for any post/attachment.

Comment: How can i get any attachment ID?

Comment: Well, you could take the image URL and search for that in the database for example. There are many ways...